# table: column width in percentage WITH min width in pixel

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

I have the following example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ivvupc?file=index.html

My table should be responsive, which means, if the window gets to small, the table should be scrollable. The basics for that are already implemented in the outer div:

```
<div style="width: 80%; height: 50%; overflow: auto">
```

The main problem is the following:
Every column has a different width in percentage.
Furthermore the second column 'State' should have a min-width, if the window gets to small.
Which means: If the window is big enough, use width: 25%, otherwise use min-width of 75px.
As mentioned above, the table should be horizontal scrollable when the table (espacially with the 75px wide 'State' column) gets to big.

Summarized:
When the window is big enough use the width of the columns in percentage.
When the window isn't big enough, show a scrollable table with column 'State' in fixed width of 75px

I've tried it with this code, but it doesn't work:

```
<th style="width: 25%; min-width: 75px">
  <div>State</div>
</th>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score -1):

I looked carefully at your code.
I have found a solution.
Please delete "table-layout: fixed" in the second line of your code.
It will work.
Best regards.